# Why isn't the matrix logarithm defined as the integral of the inverse function?

Tags: matrices, limits, logarithms, matrix-calculus, matrix-analysis

I just started to play around with the idea of the matrix logarithm. From my research, the simplest way to compute the value of the matrix logarithm is a generalization of the Taylor series of the natural logarithm — you just replace the $1$, with $I$:

$$\ln(A + I) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{-n + 1} \frac{A^{n}}{n}$$

Why not define the matrix logarithm, as the generalization of the $\ln(x)$ as the integral of the function  $\frac{1}{x}$ instead$?$

$$\ln(x) = \int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t} dt = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{1 + \frac{(x - 1)i}{n}}\frac{x-1}{n}$$

so why not define the matrix logarithm as such

$$\ln(A) = \int_{I}^{A} \frac{1}{x} dx = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{I + \frac{(A - I)i}{n}}\frac{A-I}{n}?$$

I know it's a bit weird that the limits of integration are matrices, but I don't see anything wrong with that, especially because we can just use the Riemann sum directly. Do we avoid using that definition because not every matrix is invertiable$?$ Because the two matrices in this sum don't always commute? or do we do use this definition and my reseasrch was incomplete?

Comment: This is an interesting approach. The only problems may be that the limit does not exist, or else a not invertible matrix appears. It is interesting to try an identity matrix plus a nilpotent matrix $A$ because the power series approach is a finite sum due to $A^n\to 0$.

Comment: @Somos, besides the $0$ matrix, do you have an example of matrix whose limit does not exist?

Comment: Why not define the logarithm of a matrix using the logarithm of the Jordan blocks? Take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_matrix#Functions_of_matrices).

Comment: The last integral can be rephrased as the contour integral of $\frac{1}{z}$ along the path $\gamma(t)=I+t(A-I)$ for $t\in[0,1]$, i.e., $$\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z}\,\mathrm{d}z=\int_{0}^{1}\gamma(t)^{-1}\gamma'(t)\,\mathrm{d}t.$$ This integral is well-defined, since the subalgebra of the set $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ of all real or complex $n$-by-$n$ matrices spanned by $I$ and $A$ is a commutative Banach algebra. My impression is that this approach is viable only after one learns at least a bit about functional analysis, which requires much more work than the definition based on power series.

Comment: But this integral isn't well defined, for every matrix $A$ right$?$ It's well defined for a matrix $A$, if and only if, for every $0\leq r\leq1$, the matrix $I - r(A - I)$ is invertiable right$?$

Answer (score 1):

You have the right idea, but you must start with a
[Cauchy Integral](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula) in the complex plane whose contour encloses the point of interest
$$\eqalign{
f(a) &= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\frac{f(z)\;dz}{(z-a)} \\
}$$
To extend this to the matrix case, substitute $\{a,z\}\to\{A,zI\}$ and expand the contour to enclose the entire spectrum (i.e. all eigenvalues) of $A$
$$\eqalign{
f(A) &= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint \left(zI-A\right)^{-1}\,f(z)\;dz \\
}$$
For numerical calculations, instead of Riemann sums you'll need the trapezoidal rule (modified for contour integrals). This [excellent paper](https://eprints.maths.manchester.ac.uk/1136/1/hht08.pdf) has more details.